# Upgrade PHP 5.3 to 5.4 via putty

Tags: upgrade, php

I am using Ubuntu 10.04.1 LTS Server with
PHP Version 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.19
Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu).

I login to the server via putty and want to upgrade to php 5.4. I could not find the right commands from Google.I am not expert in Linux Please help me step by step.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/343560/update-server-php-version-to-5-4-10-via-the-command-line

Answer (score 1):

It's not recommended to install a version of php that isn't provided by the default ppa's, but if you want to do it this is what you should do:

First we add a repo that contains the file we need, but as Ubuntu Server can't add repos at the default setting write the following command to be able to add repos:

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
```

After that we can add the repo by typing:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5
```

Then we can upgrade php by typing these two commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

To be sure if you have the right version type:

```
php -v
```

Comment: I am login to the sever SSh via putty.
I can not run sudo command

Comment: If I run  
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
Come this message
-bash: sudo: command not found

Comment: Current php version is 5.3.2
Requires: PHP 5.3.3 for moodle 2.5

If not recommend upgrade to php5.4 what is your suggestion.
Thanks for advise.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/377723/how-can-i-use-sudo-when-i-logged-in-with-a-ssh-key-in-putty As you're not using the server for anything serious just do as i said.

Comment: Check my result
#apt-get install python-software-properties
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  apt-utils iso-codes python-apt python-gnupginterface unattended-upgrades

Comment: Suggested packages:
  isoquery python-apt-dbg python-gtk2 python-vte python-apt-doc bsd-mailx
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  apt-utils iso-codes python-apt python-gnupginterface
  python-software-properties unattended-upgrades
0 upgraded, 6 newly installed, 0 to remove and 54 not upgraded.
Need to get 3139kB of archives.
After this operation, 15.2MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y

Comment: Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates/main apt-utils 0.7.25.3ubuntu9.14
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid/main iso-codes 3.12.1-1
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates/main python-apt 0.7.94.2ubuntu6.4
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'

Comment: Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid/main python-gnupginterface 0.3.2-9.1
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates/main unattended-upgrades 0.55ubuntu8
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-security/main python-software-properties 0.75.10.3
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates/main python-software-properties 0.75.10.3

Comment: Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'

Comment: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apt/apt-utils_0.7.25.3ubuntu9.14_i386.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'

Comment: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/iso-codes/iso-codes_3.12.1-1_all.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python-apt/python-apt_0.7.94.2ubuntu6.4_i386.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gnupginterface/python-gnupginterface_0.3.2-9.1_all.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'

Comment: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades_0.55ubuntu8_all.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/software-properties/python-software-properties_0.75.10.3_all.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
root@moodle /#

Comment: Sorry. result I can not put with <br /> tag. And comment field has character limitation. Then I put my result like above.

Comment: I don't have enough Ubuntu Server experience to help you at this point. Try to connect to the "#ubuntu-server" channel on "irc.freenode.net" and ask for help.